# Magento 2 - Upgrade Path

Tags: magento2, composer

I just wanted to find out if the there is a upgrade path to follow when upgrading a Magento 2 store via composer?

Example: 
if I want to upgrade my magento 2 store from v2.0.18 open source to v2.3.1 open source, is it fine to directly upgrade to the latest version or should I upgrade to v2.1.0 first then to v2.2.0 then to v2.3.1 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to directly upgrade to the latest version through composer. Although I would recommend that you also check all the third party codebase to make sure it won't cause any problems.

You can follow steps mentioned devdocs guide here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html to make sure you're following best practices.